# @Synchronized in a lazy init in Swift

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, thread-safety, lazy-loading

I am trying to add thread safety to a lazy init NSPersistantStoreCoordinator. I heard of the @synchronized method in objective-c which doesn"t exist in Swift. So instead I am using the "objc_sync_enter(self)" and "objc_sync_exit(self)" method. This method has been put forward in different stackoverflow threads as @synchronized replacement. I can't get it to work though. Here is my code:

```
    lazy var psc:NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {

    /* objc_sync_enter(self) */

    let persistantStoreCoordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.model)

    let documentsURL = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory()
    let storeURL = documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Model")

    var error: NSError? = nil
    if persistantStoreCoordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: storeURL, options: self.persistantStoreOptions(), error: &error) == nil {
        println("Error adding persistent store: \(error)")
        abort()
    }
    /* objc_sync_exit(self) */

    return persistantStoreCoordinator

}()
```

I am having a problem understanding where I should put the return statement in this situation. I tried to put objc_sync_exit(self) after and before the return with no luck. Is there some kind of best practice for this situation?
My real problem is that in my app, the persistentStoreCoordinator is being accessed by a thread while it's being created by another, which makes the app crash. That's why I want to use the @synchronized(self).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
    private lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator : NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {

            if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(self.filePath!) {
                let bundlePath : String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(self.filePath!.lastPathComponent.stringByDeletingPathExtension, ofType: "momd")!
                NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtPath(bundlePath, toPath:self.filePath!.stringByDeletingLastPathComponent.stringByAppendingPathComponent(bundlePath.lastPathComponent), error: nil)
            }

            let dataBaseURL : NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: self.filePath!)!
            let options : Dictionary = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : true]
            var coordinator : NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel:self.model!)
            coordinator?.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: dataBaseURL, options: options, error: nil)

            return coordinator

    }()

private func getFilePath() -> NSString {
        let paths: NSArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        let path = paths[0].stringByAppendingPathComponent("data")

        if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(path) {
            NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil, error: nil)
        }
        return path.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Database.sqlite")
    }
```

take what you need ;)
EDIT: self.filePath = self.getFilePath()

Comment: Your code is basically the same as mine. I edited my question for more clarity. My problem is that the persistentStoreCoordinator is being accessed by a thread while being created by another at the same time, which makes the app crash

Comment: you should create a singleton for the class that is allowed to create and use the PRIVATE persistentStoreCoordinator something like class var sharedDatabase : Database {
  struct Static {
   static let instance : Database = Database()
  }
  return Static.instance
 } make sure you always use Database.sharedDatabase when you want to access this class